# Why are preceding quotes automatically getting removed while reading a csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a `.csv` file like this:

```
  Col1
""word1""
""word2""
```

I am reading this file using
`pd.read_csv("filename.csv")`

But I'm not getting the correct output.

Current Output:

```
  Col1
0 word1""
1 word2""
```

Expected Output:

```
    Col1
0 ""word1""
1 ""word2""
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the signature of `read_csv` (it e.g. uses `"` as default quotechar). (hint: use `quoting=3`)

Comment: Your csv needs a delimeter so seperate colums.. by default that would be a comma in a csv-file. You could specify a seperator with ("filename.csv", sep='your seperator"). Your seperator would be "" then probably..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.reac_csv` accepts 3 arguments having to do with quotes:

> quotechar str (length 1), optional The character used to denote the
> start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter
> and it will be ignored.
>
> quotingint or csv.QUOTE_* instance, default 0 Control field quoting
> behavior per csv.QUOTE_* constants. Use one of QUOTE_MINIMAL (0),
> QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3).
>
> doublequote bool, default True When quotechar is specified and quoting
> is not QUOTE_NONE, indicate whether or not to interpret two
> consecutive quotechar elements INSIDE a field as a single quotechar
> element.

[(from the docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

In this case, seems like using `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` is enough.

```
>> import csv, pandas as pd
>> pd.read_csv('test.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

        Col1
0  ""word1""
1  ""word2""
```